# How to use _Getch?

Tags: python, cross-platform, keypress, getch

I want to detect a keypress in my code to allow the running processes to advance only if a certain time has passed and the user has requested the code to advance (must be cross-platform).

The problem is I am using Windows (so I can use msvcrt) but people that will run my code may (and probably will) have Linux or MacOS and I found some code online by Danny Yoo (http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/) which is supposed to do what I want but I don't know how to use it properly. I'm not even sure how to import it into my code even though it's in the same directory.

```
class _Getch:
    """Gets a single character from standard input.  Does not echo to the screen."""
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.impl = _GetchWindows()
        except ImportError:
            self.impl = _GetchUnix()

    def __call__(self): return self.impl()


class _GetchUnix:
    def __init__(self):
        import tty, sys

    def __call__(self):
        import sys, tty, termios
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch


class _GetchWindows:
    def __init__(self):
        import msvcrt

    def __call__(self):
        import msvcrt
        return msvcrt.getch()


getch = _Getch()
```

I tried calling `import _Getch` in my code and creating a variable `getch = _Getch._Getch()` but I don't feel this is doing what I want. What I want is to have this supposed cross-platform getch to detect if the user types `'n'` for example and then continues to the next part of the process code.

Comment: from getch import _Getch or from getch import getch ?

Comment: Put the activestate code in a local file named `getch.py` and in programs that want to use it do `from getch import getch`. Afterwards you should be able to call `getch()` to read the keyboard on the supported systems.

Comment: Use `from getch import getch` the module defines an instance of the class and gives it the same name as the module itself. If you used an `import getch`, you would need to write `getch.getch()` to use it.

Comment: @martineau How could I use this code or modify it such that I can get the character that has been typed returned to me ?

Comment: That's what `getch()` returns. Note that on Windows the `msvcrt.getch()` function sometimes needs to be called twice to get the actual character because arrow and function keys have a prefix. The activestate code doesn't really handle that properly. See Stephen Chappell's comments and code for a function named `readChar()` there. Also here's some Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=vs-2017) about how the `msvcrt.getch()` function being used works.

Comment: Thanks a lot @martineau